# Ошибка при работе pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Пожалуй сразу к теме. При создании и первой отрисовки окна должно появляться несколько кругов(все одного размера и цвета). При попытке так сделать, возникает ошибка, которая автоматически закрывает программу. Проблема в том, что даже при отключении "стоп-крана" она не выводит ошибку, из-за чего не могу понять, что не так. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать отрисовку определённого числа фигур?

```
import pygame
import random

RUNNING = True
#root = tk.Tk()
WIDTH = 960 #root.winfo_screenwidth()
HEIGHT = 960 #root.winfo_screenheight()
FPS = 30

#BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
#WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
#RED = (255, 0, 0)
#GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
#BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
TEST_COLOR = (232, 232, 232)

#SIZE_CIRCLE = random.randint(32,64)
FIRST_RANDOM_COORDINATE = random.randint(0, (WIDTH + HEIGHT) / 2)
SECOND_RANDOM_COORDINATE = random.randint(0, (WIDTH + HEIGHT) / 2)
Count_Circle = 30

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Untitled Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def Drawning_Circle(Count_Circle):
    Now_Count_Circle = 0
    while Now_Count_Circle != Count_Circle:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (32, 32, 32), 
            (FIRST_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SECOND_RANDOM_COORDINATE), SIZE_CIRCLE)
        Now_Count_Circle += 1
        
try:
    while RUNNING:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                RUNNING = False
                pygame.quit()

        screen.fill(TEST_COLOR)
        Drawning_Circle(Count_Circle)
        pygame.display.flip()
except:
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try/except` лучше переделать в такой вид:

```
try:
    ...

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    ...
```

так при ошибке в её увидите в консоле. В вашем случаем это выведите то что переменная `SIZE_CIRCLE` не существует

Comment: Спасибо,выручили!

Comment: Теперь программа уходит в вечную загрузку. Моежете дать наставления, что не так?

Comment: @Satseki они отрисовываюься но только все в одном место, поэтому создание случайных координат засунте в цикл